# TypeError: validate_on_submit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, flask

Am using [Flask web development](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920031116.do) tutorial and I have and am running to several errors; my simple web app is utilizing FlaskForm and am trying to validate the information, but am running into some trouble especially at the function validate_on_submit(). Here is my python code

```
 class NameForm(FlaskForm):
   name = StringField("What is your name?", validators=[required])
   submit = SubmitField('Submit')



 @app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def index():
     name = None
     formi = NameForm()


     if FlaskForm.validate_on_submit():
        name = FlaskForm.name.data
        FlaskForm.name.data = ''
        return render_template('index.html', form=formi, name=name)
```

my error occurs at the if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `validate_on_submit` from your form instance and not for the class. Use:

```
 if formi.validate_on_submit():
```

Answer (score 3):

This error means that `validate_on_submit` should be called with an instance of the class `FlaskForm` and not with the class itself, as shown in this example from the [docs](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html):

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def submit():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect('/success')
    return render_template('submit.html', form=form)
```

Applying to your code, the line `if FlaskForm.validate_on_submit():` should be changed to 
`if formi.validate_on_submit():`.

Comment: I really need some positive points for this question, I can't ask any other question in stack overflow without some positive points to my questions. please vote