# form.validate_on_submit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to render a template containing a form and validate information from the form. I'm getting the following error:

```
app\views.py", line 47, in signup
if form.validate_on_submit():
    TypeError: validate_on_submit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Here's my code:

*app/views.py*:

```
from .forms import SignUp
from .models import User

@app.route('/signup', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def signup():
    form = SignUp
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(
            email=form.email.data,
            username=form.username.data,
            first_name=form.first_name.data,
            last_name=form.last_name.data
        )
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return 'success'
    return render_template('signup.html', form=form)
```

*app/forms.py*

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.fields.html5 import EmailField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email

class SignUp(FlaskForm):
    email = EmailField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    first_name = StringField('First Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')
```

*app/models.py*:

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True, unique=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True, unique=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(60), index=True)
```

---

Error is from the `views.py` file at: `validate_on_submit()`. I have included my models and forms code as well. I have done as recommended in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696745/typeerror-validate-on-submit-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self) but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate `SignUp` form like so:

```
# app/views.py

from .forms import SignUp
from .models import User

@app.route('/signup', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def signup():
    form = SignUp() # HERE
    if form.validate_on_submit():
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
    form = SignUp
```

into this:

```
    form = SignUp()
```